# sql flag for max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEwk3.png]

I have a table (#update picture) containing subscriber_IDs, total, Tax_id and DOS. total is the number of visits the subscriber paid to a tax_id location for the same date of service DOS. I am trying to create another column that assigns 1 to the tax_id with the highest visit and 0 to all other Tax_ids for the same subscriber and DOS. I have many different subscribers so I need a generalized code, the picture depicts an example of only one subscriber.

desired end result column MM (desired outcome picture)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkgx7.png]

```
SELECT SUBSCRIBER_ID, Total, TAX_ID, DOS,
case WHEN Total = max(Total)  then 1 ELSE 0 END as MM 
FROM #Update3
GROUP BY SUBSCRIBER_ID, PAY_TO_PROVIDER_TAX_ID, DOS, Total
```

This is what I have but it's returning one for every row in the MM column, whereas I only need 1 in the row with Total 3, and 0 in all other rows. I need this to work on a list of different subscribers with different tax_ids and dates of service.

Comment: You are grouping by all the columns so your case expression will always return the first output. You probably need to use a subquery or a cte here.

Comment: Do you need the query for one subscriber (param subscriber_id) or for all grouped by subscriber? And I hope you don't want to save this flag in the table as it's a calculated field!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something along these lines.

```
with MyTotal as
(
    select MaxTotal = MAX(Total)
    from #Update3
)

SELECT SUBSCRIBER_ID
    , Total
    , TAX_ID
    , DOS
    , case WHEN Total = mytot.MaxTotal  then 1 ELSE 0 END as MM 
FROM #Update3
cross join MyTotal
```

Comment: I think xoxotolu wants the max(total) for each subscriber not for the whole table.

Comment: @Nikolaus that isn't what it looks like from the desired output in the post.

Comment: Okay, then I misunderstood something.